# Walking on/in/through/by a road?

Tags: word-choice

How do you "idiomatically" describe the instance of a person using their feet to traverse a road?

Is there any "wrong" way to do so?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate. It is a q with a larger scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Walking on a road* is your best option.

*I'm walking by a road* is wrong if you want to say you are walking on a road. Most native English speakers would take this to mean that you are walking alongside the road.

*Through* and *in* both shift the focus away from the act of using one's feet to traverse a road and places it on the situation around the act of walking.

> He's walking in the middle of the road.

This could mean he is in everyone's way, but it depends on the context.

> He's walking through the street.

This can mean there are a lot of people on the street that he has to walk though, he's walking aimlessly through the streets, etc. Again, the exact meaning depends on the context.